# Use regex to match start and end of string in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

Using Ruby, how can I extract the key value pairs out of the following:

```
FOO �----------......................... BAR
CODE.................................... VALUE
Parameter �---------------.............. Here is a really long string
                                         That goes across multiple lines
                                         and more lines
PARAM �-----------...................... Here is another string
```

Desired result, something similar to:

```rb
["Foo", "BAR"], 
["CODE", "VALUE"]
["Parameter", "Here is a really long string That goes across multiple lines and more lines"]
["PARAM", "Here is another string"]
```

I assume a regex would be best here to match this?

Comment: What are those `�`, `-` and `.` characters? It looks quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can be used, but may not be the *entirety* of a good solution. There are many ways to do this. Here's one.

Let's give your block of text a short name.

```
s = "FOO �----------......................... BAR
CODE.................................... VALUE
Parameter �---------------.............. Here is a really long string
                                         That goes across multiple lines
                                         and more lines
PARAM �-----------...................... Here is another string"
```

Now, let's divide it into lines.

```
s.split("\n")
# => ["FOO �----------......................... BAR", 
#     "CODE.................................... VALUE",
#     "Parameter �---------------.............. Here is a really long string",
#     "That goes across multiple lines", "and more lines",
#     "PARAM �-----------...................... Here is another string"]
```

This is all trivial.

Now split each of those.

```
s.split("\n").map { |line| line.split(/\s*\W{2,}\s*/, 2) }
# => [["FOO", "BAR"], ["CODE", "VALUE"], 
#     ["Parameter", "Here is a really long string"], 
#     ["That goes across multiple lines"], ["and more lines"], 
#     ["PARAM", "Here is another string"]]
```

And then we can use `#each_with_object` to combine text from lines represented by arrays of length 1 into the previous text.

```
s.split("\n").map { |line| 
  line.split(/\s*\W{2,}\s*/, 2) 
}.each_with_object([]) { |line, arr|
  if line.length > 1 || arr == []
    arr << line
  else
    arr.last[-1] += " #{line.first}"
  end
}
# => [["FOO", "BAR"], 
#     ["CODE", "VALUE"], 
#     ["Parameter", "Here is a really long string That goes across multiple lines and more lines"], 
#     ["PARAM", "Here is another string"]]
```